# Matrices equation $A^nX-XB^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^{n-1-k}(AX-XB)B^k$, $X-A^nXB^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k(X-AXB)B^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

It seems that for matrices $A,B$ formulae hold:

$A^nX-XB^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^{n-1-k}(AX-XB)B^k$,

$X-A^nXB^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}A^k(X-AXB)B^k$,

but I'm having difficulties proving them by induction. Inductive base holds, which is obvious, but how to prove inductive step?
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first formula, assume that $$A^{n-1}X - X B^{n-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} A^{n-1-k}(AX - XB)B^{k} $$, which is the induction hypothesis.
Then
\begin{align*} A^{n}X - XB^{n} &= A(A^{n-1}X - X B^{n-1}) + (AX - XB)B^{n-1}\\
&= A \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} A^{n-2-k} (AX - XB) B^k\right) + (AX -XB) B^{n-1}\\
&= \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} A^{n-1-k} (AX - XB) B^k\right) + (AX -XB) B^{n-1}\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} A^{n-1-k} (AX - XB) B^k .
\end{align*}

For the second formula, assume that $$X - A^{n-1} X B^{n-1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-2} A^{k}(X - AXB)B^{k} $$
,which is the induciotn hypothesis. Then

\begin{align*}
X - A^n X B^n &= (X - A^{n-1}XB^{n-1}) + A^{n-1} (X - AXB) B^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{0}^{n-2} A^k (X - AXB) B^k + A^{n-1}(X - AXB) B^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{0}^{n-1} A^k (X - AXB) B^k  .
\end{align*}